# Fully hide page with opacity animation after scrolling 250px

Tags: jquery, css

How can I achive an effect where a div's opacity changes from 1 to 0 after being scrolled down 250px? so not while scrolling. This is what I tried without the animated opacity:

```
$(function () {
    while ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
      $("#home").css({ opacity: 0 });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do that and the live **[DEMO](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=0ee475330b735c7d6c92d839c4c852e5)**. The way you tried was like `do while` functions and comes true when you think but it is not the way. You need to capture scroll and how much scrolled.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var topscroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(topscroll>250){
     $('div').css('opacity',0); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! is it also possible to animate the opacity?

Comment: I would cache `$( document )`, `$doc = $( document )`. I would also not set people off-site to see the animated example. The demo may not exist in the future and is an unnecessary step in this case.

Comment: the only problem im having now is to get the same effect when scrolling back up, `else {
      $('#home').animate({'opacity':1},250);`

Comment: `else{ $('div').animate({'opacity':1},500); }`

Comment: For some reason this is very buggy, could you edit the demo? I would really appreciate that

Comment: @GüneySaramalı What would the $('div').stop(true,true) option look like? I didnt like the css solution, I tried that

Comment: @Dan The reason was scroll functions fire itself too many times every time scroll maybe 100 times and animations are get stuck. We used stop function to clear the queue. İts fixed.